# How to create a new unsafe struct instance in C#?

Tags: c#, pointers

Actually I am working in a pointer c# aplication.
I've created this struct.

```
public unsafe struct Aris
{
    public Aris* sig;
    public int pes;
}


unsafe class Nodo
{
     // Here I am trying to create a new instance
     void insertAris(Aris *start)
     {
         Aris* newAris; 
         newAris->sig = null;
     }
}
```

I can't create a new Aris instance, and I also tried `Aris * newAris = new newAris();`, but that also failed.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like a `C++` porting to `C#` of a struct that uses a pointer as reference. In `.NET` you should avoid using pointers this way (after all, it's a framework that make use of garbage collector and pointers must be pinned in place), and you should instead use reference types (classes):

```
public class Aris
{
    public Aris sig;
    public int pes;
}

public class Nodo
{
     public void InsertAris(Aris *start)
     {
         Aris newAris = new Aris { sig = null, pes = 0 };
         // ...
     }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Solution:**
To properly define a struct you must do as such.

```
ExampleStruct es = new ExampleStruct{ exampleInt = 1, exampleInt2 = 2  };
```

As for your method, I also noticed that you are creating a undefined var `Aris* sig`, when I think you intend to do `Aris* sig = start`.